# Is it possible to call a method from the instantiating class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, owner

I have a class that is derived of UITableViewController and handles everything related with a specific type of tables. Let's call it `Class T`

In may main application class, `Class A`, I have methods to populate other areas of the screen as, for instance, a map.

While I'm populating my table within `Class T`, I would like to call the `Class A` method that plots the `x,y` points on the map.

Is this possible? What should be the correct way to do this?

When I though about this approach, I was expecting that invoking `[super ...]` inside `Class T` would call the `Class A` methods, as this is the owner class of the instance, but ofcourse it call the parent class, in my case the `UITableViewController`.

Thank you,
Pedro

Comment: It's iOS (probably Objective-C)...sorry I can't help you there.

Comment: From the given snippets it's definitely Objective-C. Tagged now.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is your main application class, you should be able to access the application instance with `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, cast it to the class `A` type, and call the APIs you need to call.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this easy approach.

Answer (score 1):

Why not define a ClassAProtocol and then add a property "classADelegate" in Class T?
ClassAProtocol will define a method like:

```
-(void)plotXYOnMapFromData:(id)someObjectContainingDataToPlot;
```

So in the Class T interface you will add:

```
@property (assign) id classADelegate;
```

and then when you instantiate, let's say from instanceA (instance of Class A), instanceT (instance of Class T) you will do:

```
instanceT.classADelegate = instanceA;
```

Finally inside Class T you can call the plotting method in this way:

```
[classADelegate plotXYOnMapFromData:myDataToPlot];
```

The advantage of the delegate pattern in this case is that Class T just need to know only one small piece of ClassA, which is the protocol, and ClassA is able to communicate with T thanks to its implementation of the protocol.

Comment: How would instanceT.classADelegate = instanceA resolve to instanceA? i.e inside Class T how do I know who instantiated the class?

Comment: maybe I can override the init method of my class T? and receive the owner as parameter ...

Comment: I could override the initWithStyle of Class T, as it inherits from class UITableViewController, and pass the owner as parameter ... the problem is that the class T is being created by IB, so there is no way to chenge the call to pass the owner ...

Comment: If in classT you define the classADelegate property to be an IBOutlet, you will see it in IB and will be able to connect to the delegate. If this is not possible, you can eventually use the awakeFromNib method of class A to set it as delegate of classT, provided the two are loaded from the same Nib. If the two instances are loaded from different Nibs, then typically you'll load the 2nd nib from a initWithNib:bundle: call on the first view controller, then after this call you will be able to set the delegate.

Comment: viggio24, it looks like a smart way to do it! the problem I see is that I don't know the type of classA inside classT in order to create the  IBOutlet (if i include classA.h inside classT.h I get a lot of errors, as expected). Can I just say that classAdelegate is of NSObject type?

Comment: you can simply declare it as "id". Normally you define a reference to a delegate in this way:
<pre><code>

Comment: "id" is enough, but you prefer you can use NSObject instead. Infact in my example I made a mistake, as it would more appropriate to declare the delegate as: @property (assign) id<ClassAProtocol> classADelegate.
Anyway "id" gives you the maximum generic approach: it is an objective-c object which is compatible with ClassAProtocol. Using NSObject you simply restrict your approach to Cocoa (which is probably good in the 99% of cases!)